# How to do sampling in sql query to get dataframe with pandas

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, sample

Note my question is a bit different here:

I am working with pandas on a dataset that has a lot of data (10M+):

```
q = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `<public table>`"
df = pd.read_gbq(q, project_id=project, dialect='standard')
```

I know I can do with pandas function with a `frac` option like

```
df_sample = df.sample(frac=0.01)
```

however, I do not want to generate the original df with that size. I wonder what is the best practice to generate a dataframe with data already sampled.

I've read some sql posts showing the sample data was generated from a slice, that is absolutely not accepted in my case. The sample data needs to be evenly distributed as much as possible.

Can anyone shed me with more light?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**

Below is a table showing how the data looks like:

[image]

Reputation is the field I am working on. You can see majority records have a very small reputation.

I don't want to work with a dataframe with all the records, I want the sampled data also looks like the un-sampled data, for example, similar histogram, that's what I meant "evenly".

I hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: What do you mean with "evenly distributed", that needs some clarification.

Comment: does this table have an integer primary key? If so, then you can randomly sample a number of primary keys in python with `pks = numpy.random.randint(0,max_pk,M)`

Afterwhich you could make a query to select rows from your table whose primary key is in your list of `pks` with `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.id IN(pks)`

Comment: Thank you Erfan, please see my update in the OP.

Comment: Thank you mitoRibo, unfortunately the table doesn't come with a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple random sample can be performed using the following syntax:

```
select * from mydata where rand()>0.9
```

This gives each row in the table a 10% chance of being selected. It doesn't guarantee a certain sample size or guarantee that every bin is represented (that would require a stratified sample). Here's a fiddle of this approach

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21d1ee/2

On average, random sampling will provide a distribution the same as that of the underlying data, so meets your requirement. However if you want to 'force' the sample to be more representative or force it to be a certain size we need to look at something a little more advanced.

Comment: Will this work with Google Big Query? OP did not mention but uses the [`read_gbq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html) method.

Comment: I believe so, see docs https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RAND-Function_57344757

Comment: Thank you Simon, is there a way to prove the data is really randomly sampled? I tried to create a full-size df and wanted to compare to the sample df, however, the full-size df cannot even be generated (table too big: 10M+)

Comment: Or do you know how to generate a df based on that size of data?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question about proving it is random. It is random by definition and the nature of randomness is that any outcome is possible so you can't really look at the sample and say whether it was generated randomly or by someone choosing records by hand. If you want to verify that the dataset has a similar distribution to the complete dataset I'd suggest repeating the frequency analysis you did to create the table in your question.